# Tool to remove unnecessary packages

Tags: apt, package-management

A couple of years ago I tried a nice utility application. It allows user to remove unnecessary packages one by one. During a removal process it gives a little description about every package and then asked if I wanted to remove that package.

Now I cant recall application name.

Can anybody identify this application based this description?

UPDATE: The application was command line application.

Comment: I think you talk about [gtkorphan](https://www.linuxlinks.com/gtkorphan/). Seems it's not available for recent Ubuntu versions anymore.

Comment: I like using `aptitude` myself; though I don't use it that often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove packages that were installed to satisfy other packages but are no longer needed by running `sudo apt-get autoremove`. There is also a program called [Deborphan](https://sites.google.com/site/easytipsforlinux/using-deborphan) that sounds similar to what you are looking for. It looks for packages that aren't being used or depended on.

Comment: Thank you! Deporphan was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the most similar utility I can think of is Synaptic

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I should have been more specific. I was using this application from command line ie. without desktop.

Comment: Then run ```sudo apt-get autoremove```